# AWS Lambda: How to access HTTP Request properties

Tags: http, aws-lambda

I am sending HTTP request to an external API, but can't figure out how to access its inner body. All the show is going on on Lambda.

For example:

```
https.get(url, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

I know how to get `res.headers`, how to get `res.statusCode`, how to get `res.status`, etc., but don't know how to get data I need. `console.log(res)` doesn't give me what I want, just a crap like below:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `res.body`? Also, it would help to know what is `https` in your example, that is, what library are you using.

Answer (score 0):

I found out [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback):

```
https.get(url, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(chunk.toString());
});
```